# How to show that $\|f\|_{L^p} \to \|f\|_{L^\infty}$ as $p \to \infty$ if $f \in L^\infty \cap L^{p_0}$ for some $0 < p_0 < \infty$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, measurable-functions

This problem is from Terrence Tao's blog: [Exercise 4](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/01/09/245b-notes-3-lp-spaces/)

> If $f \in L^\infty \cap L^{p_0}$ for some $0 < p_0 < \infty$, show that $\|f\|_{L^p} \to \|f\|_{L^\infty}$ as $p \to \infty$. (Hint: use the **Monotone Convergence Theorem**.)

I have worked this problem out using the Chebychev's inequality (or Markov's inequality by some authors) for integrals and the squeeze theorem, but I cannot work it out by the given hint using the **Monotone Convergence Theorem** since I have no idea in seeing or constructing a monotone sequence.

**EDIT**: I once had an "answer" given below, using the Simple Approximation Lemma which works well for any measurable function but there is a gap already pointed out by someone that if we write the process out, we need to justify the interchanging of limits $$\lim_{p\to \infty}\lim_{n\to \infty}||f_n||_p=\lim_{n\to \infty}\lim_{p\to \infty}||f_n||_p$$

And I asked Professor Tao on his blog and he gave a comment: "*…as Holder’s inequality will give enough quantitative continuity to interchange limits. …*" But I do not figure out in what sense does it reveal the continuity and how to see the interchangeability of limits by Holder's inequality? Also the condition $f \in L^{p_0}$ has not been used yet. (I have put foward another question but he has not replied yet)

I would be appreciate it if anyone has an idea or an answer on how to rigorously work it out.

Comment: I find this a bit mysterious too.  Taking absolute values and dividing by $||f||_{\infty}$, we can suppose that  $\sup f=1$ and $f$ is positive, and the "obvious" thing to do is look at $\lim \int f^p$, but this is a monotinc decreasing sequence of functions, not increasing. (as would be required for the theorem)..  We could use dominated convergence, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space and let $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
be a measurable function such that $||f||_{p_{0}}<\infty$ for some
$0<p_{0}<\infty$ and $||f||_{\infty}<\infty$. If $||f||_{p_{0}}=0$,
then $f=0$ a.e. and we are done. Therefore, we consider the case
$||f||_{p_{0}}>0$ only.

Clearly, by replacing $f$ with $|f|$, without loss of generality,
we may assume that $f\geq0$. Notice that in what we are going to
prove $\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}||f||_{p}=||f||_{\infty}$, the LHS
and the RHS are homogeneous. By replacing $f$ with $f/||f||_{\infty}$,
we may further assume that $||f||_{\infty}=1$. (Note that $||f||_{\infty}\neq0$,
because it is false that $f=0$ a.e.).

Let $p\geq p_{0}$, then we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
||f||_{p}^{p} & = & \int f^{p}d\mu\\
 & \leq & \int f^{p_{0}}d\mu\\
 & = & ||f||_{p_{0}}^{p_{0}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, $||f||_{p}\leq||f||_{p_{0}}^{\frac{p_{0}}{p}}\rightarrow1$
as $p\rightarrow\infty$. It follows that $\limsup_{p\rightarrow\infty}||f||_{p}\leq1$.
(In the above, we also show that $||f||_{p}<\infty$ for all
$p\geq p_{0}$. This fact will be used at later time.)

On the other hand, let $\alpha\in(0,1)$ be arbitrary and define $A_{\alpha}=\{x\in X\mid f(x)>\alpha\}$.
Since $\alpha$ is not an essential upper bound of $f$, $\mu(A_{\alpha})>0$.
Let $p\geq p_{0}$. We have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
||f||_{p}^{p} & \geq & \int_{A_{\alpha}}f^{p}d\mu\\
 & \geq & \alpha^{p}\mu(A_{\alpha}).
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore $\infty>||f||_{p}\geq\alpha\mu(A_{\alpha})^{\frac{1}{p}}.$
It follows that $\liminf_{p\rightarrow\infty}||f||_{p}\geq\alpha\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}\mu(A_{\alpha})^{\frac{1}{p}}=\alpha$.
Since $\alpha\in(0,1)$ is arbitrary, we further have $\liminf_{p\rightarrow\infty}||f||_{p}\geq 1.$

Hence, $\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}||f||_{p}=1=||f||_{\infty}.$

Comment: The OP was looking for a proof that uses the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: You have an excellent answer in another method. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may figure out what did Tao mean, and I sketch the proof as follows:

By taking the positive part and negative part respectively we may assume that $f$ is an unsigned (nonnegative) measurable function.

First suppose that $f$ is a simple function: $f = \sum^{n}_{i=1}a_i \chi_{E_{i}}$. Then we have an estimation: $$||f||_\infty \cdot \mu(\{f = ||f||_\infty\})^{1/p} \leq ||f||_p \leq ||f||_\infty\cdot \mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i)^{1/p}$$ Then by Squeese Theorem we conclude that $\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}||f||_{p} = ||f||_{\infty}$.

For general (unsigned) measurable function we may apply the Simple Approximation Lemma and the Monotone Convergence Theorem to finish the proof.

Comment: There is still a gap in that approach. For example, if we choose a
sequence of simple functions $(f_{n})$ such that $f_{n}\nearrow f$
pointwisely, then in the following argument: $\lim_{p}||f||_{p}=\lim_{p}\lim_{n}||f_{n}||_{p}=\lim_{n}\lim_{p}||f_{n}||_{p}=\lim_{n}||f_{n}||_{\infty}=||f||_{\infty}$,
we need to justify the interchanging of limits $\lim_{p}\lim_{n}=\lim_{n}\lim_{p}$.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Thanks for your comment, I may check it later.